# Invalid Conversion Error When Using Function Pointers in C++

Tags: c++

So I have been trying and battling with this for a few hours now. I am relatively new to c++ but I read about function pointers and it looked pretty useful. Essentially, what I am attempting to do below is to pass two integer values to the function foo and then multiply it by 10. However, I keep getting the following error: "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)(int, int)' [-fpermissive]".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo(int nX, int nY){
    return nX*nY;
}


int multTen(int a, int b, int (*Fn)(int, int)){
    return 10*Fn(a,b);
}

int main(){
    cout << multTen(3,4,foo(3,4)) << endl;
}
```

Your kind help in this regard is highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << multTen(3,4,foo(3,4)) << endl;
                 // ^^^^^^^ calling function foo and it's return value is passed 
                 // to multTen
```

The problem is that you are calling the `mulTen` with the return value of `foo` as a parameter instead of passing a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this?

```
cout << multTen(3,4,foo) << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Omit the (3,4) on foo. In your code sample, you are calling the foo function with the parameters (3,4) and passing the return value to multTen.